bookmark being "skipped" when scrolling
i suspect this observation is irremediable, but i wanted to ask anyways.
when there are two section bookmarks on the same page, the second one won't get "highlighted" when scrolling over the page.
\documentclass[onecolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{test1}
\vfill
\section{test2}
\newpage
\section{test3}

\end{document}

is this just something i have to accept?
the bookmark is anchored fine and if i click it, i get taken to exactly where i want.
this behaviour is not limited to the viewer. first noticed in texworks but persists in APPUL's preview and adobe's acrobat.

another showing that the placement of the second bookmark in the centre of the page does not improve the situation.


well I never noticed that the adobe reader does that, it is barely visible that the border of the flag goes from gray to a darker gray ;-). But apart from this: it looks as if the viewers do that by page, I don't think that anything in the PDF can change that.

it's actually texshop. this is why i was asking about the problem. it doesn't matter where the bookmark is placed on the page; the viewers (adobe, texshop, preview) all skip over it when scrolling, in spite of it having a valid anchor. i've added another example where the bookmark is in the middle of the page, and it still gets skipped over.

what I meant is that the viewers switch the highlight when they start a new page and then use the first bookmark on this page (or none if there isn't one).

oh i see. thanks for clarifying. but now that you notice it, don't you think it's something that should be fixed? i'm surprised this is a "reader issue" haha.

It is a viewer issue, because it also happens in pdfs that are not created with LaTeX. So probably there is not much that can be done at the LaTeX side. Fixing it on the viewer side seems feasible since the viewer knows where the anchors are and it knows what part of the page is currently in view - but since it is a common issue (I also tried some different Linux viewers and they behave the same) it is apparently difficult to implement compared to a page-by-page approach.

thanks marijn. you think we can "make some change" by hollerin' adobe or the likes?

I'm not sure Adobe is receptive to hollering, but with open source viewers such as SumatraPDF (or any viewer on Linux) you may have more luck. I was actually surprised I couldn't find a bug/issue report already for any of the editors that I checked, since it seems to be an obvious missing feature (although perhaps not a very important one).
